# Usage of "all that" and "what"

Tags: vocabulary, verbs

Although I have already raised a somewhat similar question, I still need to know more about the following:

What is the difference between these sentences? Or, could you show me the point by using another example?

- He does ***all that*** he can to assure my health and safety on the job.
- He does ***what*** he can to assure my health and safety on the job.

  Any comment or feed-back would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my feelings as a British English speaker, these sentences are similar, but saying someone does "what they can" seems to imply some kind of  noticeable limitation to their help.

Saying that someone does "all that they can" sounds like you are speaking very positively about their actions, as if they are really doing their best to help you.

Saying that they do "what they can" sounds like, while you are again saying that they are doing their best to help, perhaps their ability to do so is more limited (eg. because of time commitments, inability, etc).